# How to plot 3d mesh graph with three 1 dimensional arrays in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, plot, 3d, mesh

**I want to make a 3d mesh graph in Matlab and I have three 1 dim arrays as following**

> x={1,2,3,4,5} y={6,7,8,9,10} z=(11,12,13,14,15}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7Kg7.png)

### I need matlab code for Mesh Graph.

*Note: I have found lot of material regarding Mesh Graphs and mostly using function or single values. I need it for three 1 dimensional arrays.*

Comment: Maybe you could explain a bit more precisely, what you want to achieve. I do not fully understand how this graph should look like with your 3 1-dim arrays. How are these arrays connected in your 3d-representation?

Comment: I have added graph picture about what is needed. Can you please check that.

Answer (score 0):

If `x` and `y` are the values in plane-direction, then you need to have a 2d-`z`-array, because otherwise your coodinates are not fully defined. Every point in the plane needs a corresponding z-value. Therefore the following works:

```
x = [1 2 3]; y = [4 5 6]; z = [7 8 9; 10 11 12; 13 14 15];
mesh(x,y,z);
```